# Why does a list of open files keep appearing in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Sometimes while scrolling through a document in Notepad++, a small tan box will appear showing a list of currently opened files.

[image: Box of currently open files]

I've checked every command in the Shortcut Mapper, but I haven't been able to figure out what makes this box appear. I've lost my place by switching files a few times because of it.

**Why does this box of open files keep appearing?**

Comment: @PaulT. Turns out the shortcut is "Right click + Mouse Wheel".

Answer (score 2):

*This answer appears to be for versions of Notepad++ before 7.3.3. The program has since been updated. Please see the other answers to this question.*

---

Apparently the document switcher opens with **Right Click + Mouse Wheel**. It allows you to switch between tabs with the scroll wheel.

[Based on this unanswered Super User question from 2013](https://superuser.com/q/661981/358766), there doesn't seem to be any way to disable this shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

As someone has already said, the menu opens with Right click + Mouse Wheel. You can disable the popup in Notepad 7.9.1:

- goto Settings > Preferences > MISC. > "Document Switcher (Ctrl+TAB)"
- uncheck Enable

note:

- i'm using notepad++ 7.9.1 (the latest version)
- notepad++ 7.3.3, had this setting but wasn't the first, going off the available release notes and this youtube video's date: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-l-jBe9jho

Comment: As this is an old question and the accepted answer says that it cannot be disabled, it would be useful to state which version of Notepad++ introduced this facility, perhaps with a link to the release notes.

Comment: @AdrianHHH how's that?

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no way in Notepad++ alone (without changing the source code) there is a way using the following [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) macros:

```
WheelDown::
  GetKeyState state, RButton, P ; get state of right mouse button
  If (state = "U") {            ; U = up
    Send {WheelDown}
  }
  Return

WheelUp::
  GetKeyState state, RButton, P ; get state of right mouse button
  If (state = "U") {            ; U = up
    Send {WheelUp}
  }
  Return
```

**I tested it in Notepad++, it works.** As you can see from the code, mouse wheel is always captured but forwarded to further processing only in case when right mouse button is up.

If you want to restrict this behavior only to Notepad++, add [#IfWinActive](https://superuser.com/questions/661981/notepad-disable-document-switcher-mouse-shortcut/1248745#1248745) directive, otherwise it is system-wide.

**Note:** AHK has intentional limit of incoming events per second (here: from scroll wheel). If it is exceeded, AHK prints a warning. But you can increase the limit and you should be good to go.